# Find regions in which the roots of a third degree polynomial are real

Tags: equation-solving, complex, polynomials, conditional

I have to find the roots of a third degree polynomial in $\phi$ that depends from 3 parameters, namely $t,s,w\in \mathbb R$. In order to do that I've used the command `Solve`, in the following way:

```
Solve[
   1/6*ϕ*(t^2 + ϕ^2) - 1/2*t*(s + (t*ϕ)/2) +w - (s*ϕ)/2 
 + 1/12*t*(t - ϕ)*ϕ == 0, {ϕ}]
```

Mathematica gives me three solution, as expected, without worrying about the parameters:

```
 {{ϕ -> t/6 - (-36 s - t^2)/(3 2^(2/3) (756 s t + 2 t^3 + 
             Sqrt[4 (-36 s - t^2)^3 + (756 s t + 2 t^3 - 
                           1296 w)^2] - 1296 w)^(1/3)) + 
             (756 s t + 2 t^3 + 
             Sqrt[4 (-36 s - t^2)^3 + (756 s t + 2 t^3 - 1296 w)^2] - 
             1296 w)^(1/3)/(6 2^(1/3))}, 
  {ϕ -> t/6 + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-36 s - t^2))/(6 2^(2/3) (756 s t + 
             2 t^3 + Sqrt[4 (-36 s - t^2)^3 + (756 s t + 2 t^3 - 1296 w)^2]   
            - 1296 w)^(1/3)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (756 s t + 2 t^3+ 
            Sqrt[4 (-36 s - t^2)^3 + (756 s t + 2 t^3 - 1296 w)^2] - 
            1296 w)^(1/3))/(12 2^(1/3))}, 
  {ϕ -> t/6 + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-36 s - t^2))/(6 2^(2/3) (756 s t + 
             2 t^3 + Sqrt[4 (-36 s - t^2)^3 + (756 s t + 2 t^3 - 1296 w)^2]-
             1296 w)^(1/3)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (756 s t + 2 t^3 + 
            Sqrt[4 (-36 s - t^2)^3 + (756 s t + 2 t^3 - 1296 w)^2] - 
                1296 w)^(1/3))/(12 2^(1/3))}}
```

From now on, we will call the first output $\phi_1$, the second one with $\phi_2$ and the third one $\phi_3$.

Now, I want to explicetely find $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ such that

1. for parameters $(t,s,w)\in Z_1$, $\phi_1$ is real (while $\phi_2, \phi_3$ can be both real or both complex);
2. for parameters $(t,s,w)\in Z_2$, $\phi_2$ is real (while $\phi_1, \phi_3$ can be both real or both complex);
3. for parameters $(t,s,w)\in Z_3$, $\phi_3$ is real (while $\phi_2, \phi_3$ can be both real or both complex).

So, in order to clarify (I hope) a little bit, we have that:

- in $Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Z_3$ all the three solutions
  $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$ are real;
- in $Z_1\setminus (Z_2\cap Z_3)$ we have that $\phi_1$ is real while $\phi_2, \phi_3$ aren't;
- in $Z_2\setminus (Z_1\cap Z_3)$ we have that $\phi_2$ is real while $\phi_1, \phi_3$ aren't;
- in $Z_3\setminus (Z_2\cap Z_1)$ we have that $\phi_3$ is real while $\phi_1, \phi_2$ aren't.

My goal is to find explicitly $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$. What can I do?

I've also tried to to this:

```
Solve[1/6*\[Phi]*(t^2 + \[Phi]^2) - 1/2*t*(s + (t*\[Phi])/2) + 
      w - (s*\[Phi])/2 + 1/12*t*(t - \[Phi])*\[Phi] == 0, 
      {\[Phi]}, Reals]
```

and the output is:

```
{{\[Phi] -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-6 s t + 12 w - 6 s #1 - t #1^2 + 2 #1^3 &,1], 
          (36 s + t^2 > 0 && -378 s t - t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3] + 648 w > 0 && 
           378 s t + t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3] - 648 w >0) || 
          (36 s + t^2 > 0 && -378 s t - t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3]+648 w<0) || 
          (36 s + t^2 > 0 && 378 s t + t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3]-648 w < 0) || 
           36 s + t^2 < 0]}, 
{\[Phi] -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-6 s t + 12 w - 6 s #1 - t #1^2 + 2 #1^3 &, 2], 
           -378 s t - t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3] + 648 w > 0 && 
            378 s t + t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3] - 648 w > 0 && 
            36 s + t^2 > 0]}, 
{\[Phi] -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-6 s t + 12 w - 6 s #1 - t #1^2 + 2 #1^3 &, 3], 
         -378 s t - t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3] + 648 w > 0 && 
          378 s t + t^3 + Sqrt[(36 s + t^2)^3] - 648 w > 0 && 
          36 s + t^2 > 0]}}
```

What do these conditional expressions mean? For example, is the conditional expression after $\phi_1$ exactly $Z_1$? And also are the conditional expressions after $\phi_2,\phi_3$ respectively $Z_2,Z_3$?

I'm not sure about that, because, if it were so, we would have that $Z_i\setminus (Z_j\cap Z_k)= \varnothing$ for $i,j,k$ different, $i,j,k\in\{1,2,3\}$. But this would imply that this equation has *always* only real solutions for any values of the parameters.

---

**Mistake found:**

$Z_2\setminus (Z_1\cap Z_3)=\varnothing$, $Z_3\setminus(Z_1\cap Z_2)=\varnothing$, $Z_1\setminus(Z_2\cap Z_3)\neq \varnothing$.

So, this means that:

1. there are *no* values of the parameters such that *exactly* $\phi_2$ is real and $\phi_1,\phi_3$ are both complex;
2. there are *no* values of the parameters such that *exactly* $\phi_3$ is real and $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are both complex;
3. *there are* values of the parameters such that *exactly* $\phi_1$ is real and $\phi_2,\phi_3$ are both complex.

Obviously these conclusions are true if $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ that I want to find are exactly the ConditionalExpression after $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$.

Comment: Nice Avatar btw.

Comment: `Solve[..., Reals]` gives certain `ConditionalExpression`s. Could you check them?

Comment: I've checked them, but I don't understand them quite well because I think I have misunderstood the meaning of the conditions. I'm going to edit the post right away explaining way I don't understand.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the [discriminant of the cubic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) to determine whether the roots are real or not?  This probably works out to be equivalent to the `ConditionalExpressions` you've found, but it might be a nicer way to show it.

Comment: Do you mean "by hands"? Actually, I don't want to put myself directly in the computation, I would prefer Mathematica to do them for me :)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Ok, now I've understood what you're talking about! No, there's no reason why I shouldn't use the discriminant of the cubic polynomial to find out the values for which the solutions are real or not. I can try it. But do you think that the Conditional expressions give us exactly the same result?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: and also... If I want to use the method you've suggested, what I have to do in Mathematica? Something like Solve[\Delta>0] is enough? I'm sorry but I started using Mathematica only two days ago and I'm not so expert.

Comment: `Discriminant[]` is a built-in function.

Comment: @J.M. So, in order to isolate the region in which I have 3 distinct real roots I have to write Solve[Discriminant[]>0]?

Comment: `Reduce[]` would actually be the appropriate function in this case, since you're dealing with an inequality as opposed to an equation.

Comment: I'm going to try right now. Thank you.

Comment: Something like `RegionPlot3D[
 Evaluate@Reduce[Discriminant[eq, \[Phi]] > 0, {t, s, w}], {t, -10, 
  10}, {s, -10, 10}, {w, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 30]`

Comment: @belisariushassettled: I've read PlotPoints in the documentation center, but I don't understand what this option does practically.

Comment: It specifies the initial number of seed points to use in exploring the region.The more points you use, the more detailed (and time-consuming!) the result

Comment: This will give a complicated result but it might be what you are looking for. `poly[phi_] := 
 1/6*phi*(t^2 + phi^2) - 1/2*t*(s + (t*phi)/2) + w - (s*phi)/2 + 
  1/12*t*(t - phi)*phi

CylindricalDecomposition[
 Exists[phi1, 
  poly[phi1] == 0 && Discriminant[poly[phi1], phi1] == 0], {s, w, t}]`